# Взаимодействие между окнами

Tags: java, javafx

Не могу понять как осуществляется взаимодействие между двумя окнами в JavaFX. Имеется ввиду как я могу влиять на вью первого окна находясь во втором? Например: в первом окном у меня TableView во втором (модальном) настройки этой таблицы. Мне нужно поменять отображение некоторых из столбцов, и по возвращению в первое окно, они должны автоматически применяться.

Comment: Приложите код, напишите ,что хотели сделать и что получилось, разговор об абстрактных окнах ни к чему не приведет.